# What is a = a doing in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
a=b
```

leads to

```
error: Variable not in scope: b
```

Why doesn't the same happen with

```
a=a?
```

I've done a little testing, and every function that computes a gets stuck when computing it.

```
map (+1) a -- outputs nothing before getting stuck
toy x = 'f':x -- outputs "f before getting stuck
```

and a bunch of others get stuck.

However

```
Prelude> :type a
a :: t
```

So a is a constant of a variable type, with no constraints. As far as I can tell, evaluating it leads to some kind of infinite loop.

My guess is that it keeps trying look itself up, recursing infinitely. Is this correct, and why does it not lead to an error when compiling?

Comment: The definitions are recursive, there's a few good previous posts on it

Comment: "My guess is that it keeps trying look itself up, recursing infinitely. Is this correct, and why does it not lead to an error when compiling?" In short: yes, that's correct. It doesn't lead to an error when compiling because it's not prohibited for a definition to reference itself. And that's not prohibited because it's sometimes useful.